# How to give special characters in Trivia Game, Multiple Choice?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using the Actions on Google Trivia Game template.

Special characters `()` are not displaying in the chat window.
In google sheets, I have given in the following format.

> **Question:** How to Add an item to the end of the list
>   **Answer1:** append()
>   **Answer2:** extend()

In google assistant, it was displaying without parenthesis. How to give questions and answers with parenthesis and other special characters?

Comment: Can you give an example of the code used to parse the chat?

Comment: I didn't write any code. I used trivia templates in Actions on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good one - it looks like the processor that uses what you entered removes special characters. This does seem odd when you look at the question and the suggestion chips.

However... it makes sense if you think about how people are expected to answer the question. If you run it in "speaker" mode, it won't display the suggestion chips, but users will be expected to verbally give an answer. It is pretty difficult to give an answer with parentheses - so the system automatically removes those from what is expected.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to disable speaker mode and make it work